# Download private movie with youtube-dl from python?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to download private movie from youtube in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import youtube_dl
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL({'outtmpl': '%(id)s%(ext)s','username':'XYYXYX','password':'XXXXX'})

with ydl:
result = ydl.extract_info(
    'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=privatevideoid',
    download=False # We just want to extract the info
)

if 'entries' in result:
# Can be a playlist or a list of videos
video = result['entries'][0]
else:
# Just a video
video = result


video_url = video['url']
```

but all i get is error : this video is private.

How to do it?

Comment: I guess because of API restrictions ...

Comment: but when i use standalone windows version - it works.